# Selenium Python using username password authenticating proxies ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED

Tags: python, selenium, proxy, selenium-chromedriver

I feel like this could just be a silly mistake on my part but at the same time i do not know. I'm using python selenium to add proxies to newly opened chrome windows. Everything runs smoothly until it is time for the window to open with its new proxy. Once the window opens it reads `ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED`
I made sure that once the proxy gets found it has its brackets and quotes stripped so it is its pure text. 
I have a lot of print statements so i can tell when things successfully happen in the background procedures'. I am lost and i cannot figure out what is wrong and why the proxy will not connect, when i do it manually it connects perfectly fine but through this i get an error. here is my code.

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import time
import random
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

chrome_path = r"chromedriver.exe"
times = ""
start_page = ""
options = Options()
proxy = Proxy()
new_proxy = []
pro_sheet = open("proxies.txt", "r")

for line in pro_sheet:
    new_proxy.append(line)


def start_pages(target_page):
    j = 0
    for x in range(0, len(page_number)):
        j = j + 1
        time.sleep(3)
        print("Attempting to add fake userAgent...")
        ua = UserAgent()
        user_agent = ua.random
        print("Successfully added fake userAgent...")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Attempting to add chrome arguments...")
        time.sleep(1)
        options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
        options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
        options.add_argument("window-size=600,600")
        options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
        options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
        options.add_argument("--disable-plugins-discovery")
        options.add_argument("--proxy-server=%s" % random.choice(*new_proxy))
        options.add_argument("ignore-certificate-errors")
        print("Successfully added chrome arguments to browser window...")
        time.sleep(1)
        # print("Attempting to to initiate headless mode")
        # chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        # print('Initiated headless mode')
        print("Attempting to detach chrome...")
        options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
        print("Successfully Detached chrome...")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Attempting to add proxy...")
        time.sleep(1)

        try:
            proxy.proxy_type = ProxyType.MANUAL
            proxy.autodetect = False
            proxy.http_proxy = proxy.ssl_proxy = proxy.socks_proxy = random.choice(*new_proxy)
            options.proxy = proxy
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        time.sleep(1)
        print("Successfully added proxy...")
        print("Browser number " + str(j) + ", is using proxy: " + str(*new_proxy))
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Attempting to add capabilities and options...")
        capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
        proxy.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path, options=options)
        print("Successfully added capabilities and options...")
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.set_window_position(0, 0)
        driver.get(target_page)
        content = driver.get(target_page)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
        text = soup.get_text()

        if "ERR" in text:
            print("FATAL ERROR. Proxy not available.")
            driver.quit()
        else:
            print("Browser number " + str(j) + " has opened successfully...")


while times == "":
    times = input("How many pages do you want?\n")

# url = input("Yeezy Supply or Adidas?""\nEither 'YS' or 'Adidas'\n")
# url_choice = url.lower()

page_number = list()
for i in range(0, int(times)):
    page_number.append(times)

# if url_choice == 'ys':
# start_page = 'https://yeezysupply.com/'
# start_pages(start_page)
# elif url_choice == 'adidas':
# start_page = 'https://www.adidas.com/yeezy'
# start_pages(start_page)
start_page: str = 'https://www.adidas.com/yeezy'
start_pages(start_page)
```

the proxy it is pulling is `x3LVAU3.nyc.unknownproxies.com:21021:mferraro2304:o3VXtvjHpWr4`
I dont think there is anything wrong with it as when i test it it works perfectly fine.

**NOTE:** I know that the beautiful soup yields an error, i still haven't gone thorough the entire documentation yet.

Comment: As for using proxies, I've started to use selenium-wire

Comment: @josifoski ill look into this thanks.